# How to give value from select box everytime increase button of dynamically Input Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery dynamic table inputs in my form.Whenever i select country,i get the value from select box.But when i increase dynamic button (+) and again select the country from select box from another input field.i get same value of country from first selectbox field

```
<table class="dynamic-fields-table">
     <thead>
            <tr>
                <th >Country</th>
                <th >City</th>
                 <th></th>
            </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-role="dynamic-fields">
        <tr class="form-inline">
         <td>
             <select name="country[]" class="form-control">
                <option value="1">USA</option>  
                <option value="2">Russia</option>
                <option value="3">Japan</option>
             </select>
         </td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" name="city[]" class="form-control">
        </td>
        <td>
            button  data-role="add">Add</button>-  // button for increasing or decreasing input
        </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

In script file.When I select country at first it will come value right in console.but when i increase input form then i select again another country then value of country will give same as first time selected.So how should i give value of country i selected everytime i increase dynamically input button

```
$(document).on(
        'click',
        '[data-role="dynamic-fields"],
        function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var container = $(this).closest('[data-role="dynamic-fields"]');
            new_field_group = container.children().filter('.form-inline:first-              child').clone();
            new_field_group.find('input').each(function(){
                $(this).val('');
            });
            container.append(new_field_group);
            updatecity()
       }
    );
$(document).on('change', " select[name='country[]']", function(){
        updatecity();
  });

function updatecity(){
    $country = $(" select[name='country[]']").val();
    console.log($country)
}
```

Comment: The code available is not enough to replicate or understand what you need. Can you add more code on + and - buttons and their actions?

Comment: @VidiyaPrasanth Is that really neccessary ?

Comment: or try making a runnable code snippet in stack overflow. If I can't see what is wrong by running the code, it is not easy to help.

Comment: @VidiyaPrasanth I have updated my question.please look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, `updatecity` always gives you the value of the first result of `$(" select[name='country[]']")`. While the values of the other dropdown lists are ignored.

```
function updatecity(){
    $country = $("select[name='country[]']").val();
    console.log($country)
}
```

To make each dropdown list's call to `updatecity` behave with respect to its own value, you can add a parameter to `updatecity` to tell which country to update.

```
function updatecity($target){
    $country = $target.val();
    console.log($country);
}
```

Having the function signature changed, you will also need to update places where you call `updatecity`

```
$(document).on(
    'click',
    '[data-role="add"]',
    function(e) {
        // ...
        updatecity($("select[name='country[]']"))
    });
```

```
$(document).on('change', "select[name='country[]']", function(e){
   updatecity($(this));
});
```

Also, the code you're showing will insert a new inline-form whenever `<tbody>` is clicked, so I changed the selector from `[data-role="dynamic-fields"]` to `[data-role="add"]`

As a sidenote, I notice that `updatecity` doesn't actually do anything except logging a value. You might want to have its behavior match its name.

Below I've attached a code snippet for demonstration.

```js
$(document).on(
        'click',
        '[data-role="add"]',
        function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var container = $(this).closest('[data-role="dynamic-fields"]');
            new_field_group = container.children().filter('.form-inline:first-child').clone();
            new_field_group.find('input').each(function(){
                $(this).val('');
            });
            container.append(new_field_group);
            updatecity($("select[name='country[]']"))
       }
    );
$(document).on('change', "select[name='country[]']", function(e){
    updatecity($(this));
  });

function updatecity($target){
    $country = $target.val();
    console.log($country)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="dynamic-fields-table">
     <thead>
            <tr>
                <th >Country</th>
                <th >City</th>
                 <th></th>
            </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-role="dynamic-fields">
        <tr class="form-inline">
         <td>
             <select name="country[]" class="form-control">
                <option value="1">USA</option>  
                <option value="2">Russia</option>
                <option value="3">Japan</option>
             </select>
         </td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" name="city[]" class="form-control">
        </td>
        <td>
            <button  data-role="add">Add</button><!-- button for increasing or decreasing input-->
        </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```